# Javascript Scope using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I am having trouble understanding why this is occurring. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  var mFormHelper = new FormHelper("form_add_ftransaction");
  var mThing = $("#mThing");

  form_add_ftransaction.submit(function(event){

    //var mFormHelper = new FormHelper("form_add_ftransaction"); <-- unless i uncomment this it doesn't seem to work

    var mloader = new Loader();

    mloader.setLoading(mThing);//<----- mThing is available in scope...

    mFormHelper.clearForm(); //<-------doesn't work unless mFormHelper is redeclared. Why not?

  });
});
```

Why is it that the variable 'mThing' is accessible inside the jQuery .submit(function(){}) but 'mFormHelper' is not?

The error I get if i don't redeclare the mFormHelper is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined"

The FormHelper class is:

```
function FormHelper(formId){
    context = this;  //<--------------------------THIS WAS THE PROBLEM
    this.form = $("#"+formId);
    this.validate = function(){
        var valid = true;
        var requiredFields = context.form.find(".required");

        requiredFields.each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("form_highlight");
            var field = $(this);
            if(field.attr("type") !=""){
                field.type = field.attr("type");
            }
            //alert(field.attr("data-type"));
            if(field.attr("data-type") == "radiogroup"){
                if(field.find("input:checked").get() ==""){

                    field.addClass("form_highlight");
                    valid = false;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            if((field.val() == "" || field.val() == null) && field.attr("data-type") != "radiogroup"){

                field.addClass("form_highlight");
                valid = false;
            }


        });
        return valid;
    };
/**
 * Method markRequiredFields
 *
 * Adds an asterisk in front of label for all required fields in the form. required fields are noted with the '.required' class.
 */
this.markRequiredFields = function(){
    var requiredFields = context.form.find(".required");
    requiredFields.each(function(){
        field = $(this);
        var label = $("label[for='"+field.attr('id')+"'");
        var str = label.html();
        if(str != undefined){
            label.html("*"+str.replace("*", ""));
        }

    });
}
this.clearForm = function (){
        this.form.find(':input').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden, :checkbox, :radio').val('');
        this.form.find(':checkbox, :radio').prop('checked', false);
        this.form.removeAttr("class", "form_highlight");

}
```

}

Comment: UM, it is in scope in that example.

Comment: Are you getting an error saying that mFormHelper is not in scope? Cause it seems to be. It looks like something else is going on. What error are you getting in the console?

Comment: i Just added something to the question. the error I get if i don't have the mFormHelper redeclared is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined" .find is called in the method .clearForm().

Comment: On what element, this looks like that `.find()` is chained to undefined element.

Comment: `this.form` is a DOM node, not a jQuery collection.

Comment: Sorry. I added more to me question again. I defined this.form = $("#"+formId); so it is a jQuery object

Comment: The biggest mystery is why `form_add_ftransaction.submit(...)` doesn't generate an error when `form_add_ftransaction` is not defined.

Comment: You got it. thats why im throwing this question out there. it seems very odd to me.

Comment: Have a look through your unsimplified code. Something must be assigning to `form_add_ftransaction`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved the issue after your helpful comments instructed me that it should be in scope.

In my FormHelperClass the problem was:

```
function FormHelper(formId){
    context = this;  //<-------THIS WAS THE PROBLEM
    this.form = $("#"+formId);
    this.validate = function(){
        $valid = true;
    .......
```

should have been

```
var context = this;
```

always something so simply...

thanks guys.

Comment: Chris, you similarly need `var field = ...` in a couple of places.

Comment: And `context` isn't really needed. It's only ever used for `context.form` so assign `var $form = $("#"+formId);` instead, then replace `context.form` with `$form` all through.

Comment: the reason I assigned the form as a property of FormHelper (i.e. `this.form = $("#"+formId);` is so that outside of the class I could access it(ex. `mFormHelper.form` ) if I assign it as `var $form = $("#"+formId);` inside the FormHelper class, am I wrong to think I could not access the $form variable? Also the reason I declared the variable `context = this;` is because within a method `this` does not refer to what I want it to. I am definitely open to better methods. I am fairly new to using OOP with javascript.

Comment: You're right on both points. Local vars are private, though they can be exposed through methods. If you are going to do other things with `context` and `.form` then yes, stick with what you have.